# How to configure the power off button to just power off instantly in Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome)

Tags: gnome, 17.10, shutdown

I would like my Computer to just power off when I press the hardware `Power` Button. Instead I dialog with a countdown and Options (Cancel, Restart, Power Off) comes up. How to disable this dialog and power off immediately?

Or at least, how to set the countdown to much, much less then 60 seconds?

Comment: There is no easy way according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/242129/gnome-3-how-to-set-power-button-to-shutdown-instead-of-suspend)

Comment: @mikewhatever there is now a `set-chassis vm` workaround in the same place.

Comment: I've opened a PR that will make `set-chassis embedded` works like `vm`, but preserves the airplane mode functionality: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/-/merge_requests/156

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04

```
gsettings set org.gnome.SessionManager logout-prompt false
```

or you can also try

```
gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true
```

Comment: On 22.04 the first one removes the dialog but not the delay, so the computer doesn't shut down immediately... The second schema doesn't exist on this system.

Comment: for Ubuntu Mate 22.04 the relevant keys are ```
gsettings set org.ayatana.indicator.session suppress-logout-restart-shutdown true
gsettings set org.mate.session logout-prompt false
gsettings set org.mate.session logout-timeout 10
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20.10 I found it under `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power`. The default value is `interactive`, but you can change it to `shutdown`.

Change it using `gsettings` like pasha's answer, or use `dconf-editor`, which has a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
org.gnome.gnome-session logout-prompt 'false'
```

and

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'shutdown'
```

worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. A nice side effect is, that this also causes immediately Power-Off by HDMI-CEC controls.

Comment: On 22.04 it removes the dialog but not the delay, so the computer doesn't shut down immediately...

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are other desktop environments like:
com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power
or
org.mate.power-manager

There might be the correct change, but for the wrong environment...

a more generic search of your gsettings can also help:
`gsettings list-recursively | grep button` on my system additionally shows:

```
.
.
.
com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power power-button-action 'suspend'
com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-hibernate 'hibernate'
com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-power 'suspend'
com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-suspend 'suspend'
com.canonical.unity.settings-daemon.plugins.power button-sleep 'hibernate'
```

As answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1274138/how-to-disable-the-behaviour-of-the-power-button-on-ubuntu-20lts) by WU-TANG